# jQuery: Accordion - Change header text but don't change icons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

so I use the accordion that jQuery offers.
Inside the accordion, I put some input fields.
Lets say I have an accordion with 3 rows (which you can expand and close).
Now when someone inputs something wrong into one of the input fields, the header of the row shall change to something like "error in here!" or whatever.
jQuery makes these expandable rows with icons by putting a span into the h3.
It looks like this (I use just a selfmade example here to explain the syntax!!):

```
<h3 id='some_id'>
    <span style='color:#FF0000;'>HELLO!</span>
    HEY!
</h3>
```

Now when I want to change the header, using
`$("h3[id='some_id']").html('HI THERE!');`
or 
`$("h3[id='some_id']").text('HI THERE!');` 
won't work, as they also delete the span within the h3.
Is has to stay there to show the icons though!

I also tried 
`$("h3[id='some_id']").children().html('HI THERE!');`
but that changes the span only....and I want the span to only NOT change.
How can I change the 'HEY!' into 'HI THERE!' only, not deleting the span?

I hope this isn't written to complicated, I don't know how to express myself any better.
Sorry ;-)

EDIT: here is a fiddle for example
[jsfiddle.net/aLWPJ](http://jsfiddle.net/aLWPJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content",
        active: false,
    });

    var spanHTML = $("h3#ui-accordion-1-header-0 span").clone().wrap('<p>').parent().html();
    $("h3#ui-accordion-1-header-0").html(spanHTML+'HI THERE!');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aLWPJ/1/

EDIT: Changed in response to comment (again).

Comment: Thanks, but that changes the value of the span.
I want to change the value of the h3 itself

Comment: Acctually, yes, for my posted example, that works fine.
jQuery itself seems to have a problem with that, though :(
If I use it on my accordion, it still overwrites the <span>

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aLWPJ/
That code shows how it looks like at the beginning, notice the arrows of the accordion.
I want to write "Hi there" to the header AND keep the arrows where.
If you use the commented code, it will replace the text in the header BUT also kills the arrows (because somehow the <span> is missing then)

Comment: Third time's a charm. Updated answer.

Comment: Great, that work here!
Who would have thought that it would be this complicated to just change the title? :D
Great work, thank you for helping me out!